# Aggregate Jenkins build logs stored in ElasticSearch

Tags: database, elasticsearch, jenkins, logging

I'm storing my Jenkins build logs in ElasticSearch with the Jenkins Logstash plugin.

My configuration looks sort of like this:

[image: Logstash config]

That part works great, but I'd like to view the full log in Kibana.

The plugin incrementally sends the results to ES and breaks on each newline. That means a long log can look something like this in Kibana:

[image: Log as seen in Kibana]

Where each line is a massive JSON output containing tons of fields I do not care about. I really only care about the message field.

I'm reading about [aggregators](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-script) right now that appear to be what I need, but my results are not coming out to what I'd like.

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "aggs" : {
        "buildLog" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "data.url"
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Prints out a large glob of json that does not have what I need.

In a perfect world, I'd like to concatenate every message field from each  data.url and fetch that.

In SQL, an individual query for this might look something like:

```
SELECT message FROM jenkins-logstash WHERE data.url='job/playground/36' ORDER BY ASC
```

Where 'job/playground/36' is one example of every data.url.

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: It is probably better to install logstash and send a single event for every build with only the fields you care about. For ex. for build 36 ingest one document with exactly the fields you want from the build log. That way you will have a single document (with fields) for every build. Easier to search/ aggregate

Comment: Perhaps, but we have some logs that are hundreds of megabytes. I kind of like the behavior that they are incrementally sent. Sending logs all at once could potentially fail because of how large they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Better answer than before.

I still ended up using FileBeat, but with ELK v6.5.+ Kibana has a logs UI! https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/logs-ui.html

The default config from FileBeat works fine with it.

__

Old answer:

I ended up solving this by using FileBeat to harvest all logs, and then using the Kibana Log Viewer to watch each one. I filtered based on `source` and then used the path where the log was going to be.